# Installing moreutils on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, yum, moreutils

How do I install [moreutils](https://rentes.github.io/unix/utilities/2015/07/27/moreutils-package/) on the default image Amazon EC2 instance?  The instances are built off of CentOS but presumably have their own packages repo since

```
sudo yum install moreutils
```

fails with

```
No package moreutils available.
```

What is the yum repo I need to install moreutils?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The epel repo is on the default Amazon server but in not enabled by default.  You can use it as follows:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo epel install moreutils
```

Note that epel has a very old version of moreutils (0.40 when 0.61 is out), which does not include `chronic`.

Answer (score 4):

For update amazon linux, you can run following commands

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum install moreutils
```

Answer (score 1):

The EPEL repository has it, and other things. It works with Amazon Linux as well as CentOS, Fedora etc. (see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). To install the config that enables that repo, `yum install epel-release`.

Comment: I tried this and was informed `Package epel-release-6-8.9.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version`, yet `cronic` (part of moreutils) gives `command not found`

Comment: - The `epel-release` package installs the epel repo config so you can then update yum again and install the `moreutils` package from that new repo.
- It's spelled `chronic`, surprisingly.

Comment: `sudo yum update` does nothing.  I still get `No package moreutils available`.

Comment: Possibly something funny about Amazon's distro? https://serverfault.com/questions/497169/installing-from-epel-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: Btw, apologies as I mis-spoke when I said "update yum", being in a very Debian mindset at the time. In yum, "update" means "upgrade", which isn't really relevant.